# using new columns in the temp table added by alter table not work

Tags: sql-server-2000, alter-table

I have a problem that the new added column can't be used in the further comments.

I have a temp table built by "select into" then I need to add an identity column by "alter table". But when I want to use the new column in a "join", I got an error "Invalid column". please note that, these commands could work separately.

I think the reason is, the new column is not found by the compiler and it give an error before running it. 
Is there a solution for that ?

I have got this problem in sql server 2000 and it seems in a newer version, the problem is not there.

```
create table #tmp_tb
(name varchar(4), val int)
insert into #tmp_tb values('ab',1);
insert into #tmp_tb values('abc',2);
select * from #tmp_tb
alter table #tmp_tb add id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1);
select * from #tmp_tb
select id,name,val from #tmp_tb
```

An error occurred :

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 9
>   Invalid column name 'id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last line with

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'select id,name,val from #tmp_tb';
```

Indeed, the parser doesn't know about the new column yet. By passing it through sp_executesql you avoid this.

Comment: Thank you very much. The dynamic SQL has well saved the  problem.